# Django updates model instead of inserting (pk=None) (INSERT INTO QUERY)

Tags: django

I'm trying to save a model entry but django insists on updating old entries instead of creating new ones. Here is my code for creating a new entry:

the print statment show log_entry.pk = None before save and log_entry = old_entry.pk after save.

```
    log_entry = QuoteResponseLog()
    log_entry.quote_response = self
    log_entry.manager = manager
    log_entry.message = action.log()
    print(log_entry)
    log_entry.save(force_insert=True)
    print(log_entry)
```

Edit: QuoteResponseLog model ([Django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils))

```
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel
class QuoteResponseLog(TimeStampedModel):
    quote_response = models.ForeignKey(
        QuoteResponse
    )

    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        Manager
    )

    message = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.created) + " : [" + str(self.manager) + "] : " + self.message + "(" + str(self.pk) + ")"
```

EDIT 2: 
Log entry from actual sql query:

```
{u'time': u'0.003', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'INSERT INTO "quote_hub_quoteresponselog" ("created", "modified", "quote_response_id", "manager_id", "message") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)\' - PARAMS = (u\'2014-09-08 11:57:10.150000\', u\'2014-09-08 11:57:10.172000\', 6, 3, u\'Godk\\xe4nnde\')'}
```

EDIT3: SQLQuery inserted in dbshell works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was trivial, a cascade delete. Deleted self before assignment to lg_entry.quote_response.